# URLs of nested sub pages in Site.com

Tags: site.com

I would like to have a page named "Meet the team" with a URL of example.com/about/meet-the-team/

I also would like a paged named "About" to have a URL of example.com/about/

**How can I do that?**

I created "About" already, and it's accessible at example.com/about/

I created "Meet the team" but it's only accessible at example.com/meet-the-team/

Even if I drag and nest "Meet the team" under "About" in the Site Pages tree view, the URL is still example.com/meet-the-team/

I tried creating a folder named "About" from the All Site Content view, and then I dragged the "Meet the team" and "About" pages under it... The URL for "Meet the team" was example.com/about/meet-the-team which is good but the URL for "About" was example.com/about/about/ which is bad

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use alias redirects to have the /about and /about/ redirect to /about/about.  Alias redirects perform the redirect on the server side, so it is transparent to the user.  They will never see the /about/about URL.  As far as I can tell, there isn't a simpler way to achieve what you want.

Under Site Configuration click URL Redirects and create two alias redirects.  One that redirects from /about to /about/about and another one that redirects from /about/ (note the trailing slash) to /about/about.

[image: Site.com Alias Redirect]

Comment: Thanks, Peter. That's actually what we're doing now, but the page 404's if there are URL parameters such as ?id=2jfdh

Comment: If you use the "matchless alias" I suggest in my answer, this should work and not generate 404s.

Answer (score 1):

**PS** The question is about Site.com not Sites so this answer is irrelevant.

Take a look at the [URL Rewriting with Sites](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2010/05/url-rewriting-for-your-customizing-your-site-urls.html) blog post.

Implementing `Site.UrlRewriter` will allow you to map URLs that are good for end-users to the flat Visualforce page URLs.

Comment: Thanks Keith. That would help with Force.com Sites but my question is in regards to Site.com

I do see that there is a section for URL Redirects in Site.com where you can see up aliases, but I was hoping there would be another way.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Peter's answer above is generally correct, if cumbersome. If you're having 404's with URL parameters, you want to set up a "matchless alias."

To ignore the query string, inside site.com when you use Site Configuration > URL Redirects to create your new redirect, select `Alias` for Redirect Type and then make sure the `Match` checkbox is NOT checked. You'll then have a matchless alias that will ignore the query string.